# re-rendering template when changing property from click event

Tags: meteor

i would like to trigger the visibility of a block in my handlebars template from an onclick function. i can use sessions and a helper function to get this to work but it seems overkill.

```
<template name="eventlist">
   {{#each eventcollection}}
    <div class="eventcontent">
     name: {{name}} <br>
     {{#if showdetail}}
       detail: {{detail}}
     {{/if}}
    </div>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

could it be possible to make it work somehow like this?

```
Template.eventlist.events = {
   'click .eventcontent': function() { this.showdetail = true}
}
```

meteor would just need to check if any attribute of this changed after the event completed and then rerender the template

Answer (score 0):

Why bother Meteor? Such things were easy to achieve in the ancient Javascript days:

```
<template name="eventList">
    {{#each eventCollection}}
        <div class="eventContent">
            name ...
            <span class="eventHidden" style="display: none;">
                detail ...
            </span>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>


Template.eventList.events({
    'click .eventContent': function(e) {
        $(e.target).find('.eventHidden').toggle();
    },
});
```

Comment: yes i agree but for example imagine a different reactive element in the same dom makes meteor rerender this part of the dom. i'd have to listen to that and reshow the element. things start getting messy

Comment: Show me a real use case - imagination is a great tool, but it's better not to use it with generating software problems :) Anyway, in such case yo need to store the state somewhere, and you probably don't intend to share it between clients - so a session will be a proper solution. But here's my thought: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it .

Comment: actually that use case actually appears in my app. as soon as i change one of the other reactive elements in my eventcontent div meteor rerenders it and my detail element is hidden

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where are the other elements, can you isolate them or put in another template?